# How to use map types to define a type for `Object.keys`?

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

I want to define a more strict `Object.keys` function using typescript mapped types.

## Example:

Let's say I have an object defined with `const`:

```
const myObj = {
  a: 'some value',
  b: 5
};
```

When I use `Object.keys` on this object, the returning type is `string[]`

```
const keysOfMyObj = Object.keys(myObj); // `const keysOfMyObj: string[]`
```

## Question:

Instead, I'd like this type to be more specific. Instead of returning the type `string[]`, I'd prefer if `Object.keys` returned the type `("a" | "b")[]`.

**Desired type:**

```
const newKeysOfMyObj = myKeys(myObj); // `const newKeysOfMyObj: ("a" | "b")[]`
```

## What I've tried:

I think this can be accomplished using [typescript mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types).

I've defined a type that asserts a type is an object's values are the same as the keys:

````
type Keys<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: P;
};

let myObjKeysOnly: Keys<typeof myObj>;

// resulting type:
// ```
// let myObjKeysOnly: {
//   a: "a";
//   b: "b";
// }
// ```
````

I've tried to implement this function as just a typed wrapper over `Object.keys`:

```
function myKeys<T>(obj: T) {
  return Object.keys(obj) as (Keys<T>);
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `keyof` :

```
function myKeys<T>(obj: T): keyof T[] {
  return Object.keys(obj) as any;
}

const x = myKeys({ a: 123, b: 123 });
```

## More

Moving types : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/moving-types.html